# DVItoPDF gives an error

Tags: graphics, pdf, eps, dvipdfmx

I have previously compiled my tex file with images, and everything worked alright.
Lastly, I have changed only the text in my tex file and when compiling the pdf I received in error of DVItoPDF due to an image. However I did not modify the image with respect to the previous compilation. I think the problem comes from the font, but I cannot see why it was working before and not anymore

Here is the error message:

```
"Operand stack:
   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   Arial-Bold
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1910   1   3   %oparray_pop   1909   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   1893   1   3   %oparray_pop   1787   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   %array_continue   --nostringval--   1868   3   4   %oparray_pop
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1167/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:82/200(L)--   --dict:199/256(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 19565
GPL Ghostscript 9.05: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
** WARNING ** Filtering file via command -->gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sPAPERSIZE=a0 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false -dGrayImageFilter=/FlateEncode -dAutoFilterColorImages=false -dColorImageFilter=/FlateEncode -sOutputFile=/tmp/dvipdfmx.Xn9tqR6 ./images/verif_thetaK_multiplot.eps -c quit<-- failed. ** WARNING ** Image format conversion for "./images/verif_thetaK_multiplot.eps" failed...
** ERROR ** pdf_ref_obj(): passed invalid object.

Output file removed."
```

The [image](http://heberg-fichiers.informatique13.com/uploads/973c6f2954.eps) in eps who seems to be the source of error (made using gnuplot).

The answer to `gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sPAPERSIZE=a0 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false -dGrayImageFilter=/FlateEncode -dAutoFilterColorImages=false -dColorImageFilter=/FlateEncode -sOutputFile=/tmp/dvipdfmx.Xn9tqR6 ./images/verif_thetaK_multiplot.eps -c quit`

is

```
Error: /typecheck in /findfont
Operand stack:
   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   Arial-Bold
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1910   1   3   %oparray_pop   1909   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   1893   1   3   %oparray_pop   1787   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   %array_continue   --nostringval--   1868   3   4   %oparray_pop
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1167/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:82/200(L)--   --dict:199/256(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 19565
GPL Ghostscript 9.05: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

Comment: In your context, exactly what is DVItoPDF? I can think of two ways, so it is kind of important to know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Yes sorry, the name of the command is "dvipdfmx".  I thought DVItoPDF was the name of the command (it is its name in Kile).

Comment: Do you mind preparing a minimal example and can we see the image in question. That `Arial-Bold` looks *interesting*, but it would be nice to have something we can test on our own systems.

Comment: I added the image. What exactly do you want to test on your system? Tex file, gnuplot image?

Comment: That is not an added image, That is a screen show, I'm assuming you are not including the screen shot into your document. I;d like to see a full minimal LaTeX document that include that image that give you problems, such that I can test that same LaTeX doc on my system. For that I also need the actual image file that is being included. Without any off these things we can only guess what is wrong. We do not even know the image format being used.

Comment: You can see on the screenshot that this is an eps, and I did not add it because we cannot add eps on this website. I do not know how I can to give you the eps image.

Comment: The error message suggests there's a problem with the PostScript code in your image file `images/verif_thetaK_multiplot.eps`. I don't know why editing just the document text should trigger the error (unless, perhaps, the code in the image file hasn't reset the graphics state). What happens if you try to run `gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sPAPERSIZE=a0 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false -dGrayImageFilter=/FlateEncode -dAutoFilterColorImages=false -dColorImageFilter=/FlateEncode -sOutputFile=/tmp/dvipdfmx.Xn9tqR6 ./images/verif_thetaK_multiplot.eps -c quit`

Comment: @lambertmular `gv` can also display PDF.

Comment: @lambertmular --- You can make the `eps` file available for download from an external site and add a link here.

Comment: Perhaps it's related to https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=732440

Comment: GhostScript failed to convert your EPS file ./images/verif_thetaK_multiplot.eps to PDF.
Maybe it could not locate a font Arial-Bold used in your EPS file. Please check your GhostScript installation.

Comment: I solve the problem by changing from Arial-Bold to Helvetica-Bold

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slightly longer comment

This sample file works just fine

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{973c6f2954.eps}
\end{document}
```

compiled using `latex` and `dvipdfmx` on TeX Live 2013 (frozen) on Linux.

Comment: I use your latex code to check and the `dvipdfmx` part still does not work on my computer. I have the same error message than previously. I am also on linux.

Comment: Which LaTeX distribution? Usually listed in the first line of the `.log` file

Comment: The first line of my `.log` file is `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian) (format=latex 2013.11.13)  8 JUL 2014 15:17`

Comment: So basically you are using a LaTeX installation from 2009! A lot has happened since 2009. Please update your LaTeX installation.

Comment: Also which `gs` version are you using? Mine is GPL Ghostscript 9.05 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: It is strange I have the 2009 version of Latex since I install it for the first time in 2014 with the repository on ubuntu. How can I know the version of gs I have?

Comment: Usually it is not a particularly good idea to get LaTeX from a Linux dist as they are often very far behind. Though recent ubuntu has a fairly rencent TeX Live. However, AFAIK the linux dists does not update their LaTeX when LaTeX get updates. Thus I typically recommand Linux users to install it manually and tell your Linux favour that you are using something similar to the Linux dists TL version. The GS versions is shown via `gs -v`

Comment: I update my version of Latex to TeX Live 2014and my version of `gs` is also GPL Ghostscript 9.05. However I have still the same error as previously when compiling the file

Comment: My file or yours? Are you using TL14? Are you sure?

Comment: I use exactly the code you wrote in your answer. The first line of my `.log` file is `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=latex 2014.7.8)  8 JUL 2014 16:13`. It did not solve my problem and now I have a new one: the legends are on top of the graphs

Comment: Then I have no idea what is going on on your side. The example I posted works just fine on my system.